# Checking remaining time from setTimeout

Tags: javascript

This code finds the remaining time in a `setTimeout` but does not print it when I want to print it to the console.
It calculates the remaining time very well, but as I said, when I want to print the remaining time, it processes it undefined to the console.

I have no idea how to do it, guys. Can you help me?

```js
(function () {
var nativeSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;

window.bindTimeout = function (listener, interval) {
    function setTimeout(code, delay) {
        var elapsed = 0,
            h;

        h = window.setInterval(function () {
                elapsed += interval;
                if (elapsed < delay) {
                    listener(delay - elapsed);
                } else {
                    window.clearInterval(h);
                }
            }, interval);
        return nativeSetTimeout(code, delay);
    }

    window.setTimeout = setTimeout;
    setTimeout._native = nativeSetTimeout;
};
}());
const time = window.bindTimeout(function (t) {(t + "ms remaining");});
console.log(time)
window.setTimeout(function () {console.log("All done.");}, 1000);
```

Comment: is it just me or does this seem extremely overly-complicated code? you are setting time to be a function which passes a function that calls a function that is then a sub-function of another function? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Rick Am I trying to get the remaining time in setTimeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some issues with your code:

- Your listener function (`function (t) {(t + "ms remaining")}`) is not doing anything: it's computing the value of `t + "ms remaining"` but it's not returning it neither logging it or anything. If you want it to work you need to add a `console.log` that uses that value.
- Your `bindTimeout` function has an `interval` argument, but it's never used in your code: if you don't provide the interval your `setInterval` won't ever start, and you won't see any message.

Here's how you can fix this: you need to create a variable in the scope of your function so that its value can be edited. The return value of `window.bindTimeout` will be a function that returns the current value that you get from the handler.
Returning a function is the only way to get a changing value: the only alternative would be using a class, but it would require a different structure.

---

**Edit: final (I hope) version**

To get the exact elapsed time (without having quantized values determined by the interval) you need to save the date in which the timer has been set, to later compare it with the current date.

I think this is the most you can get: this supports only one "custom" timer at a time; to support multiple at the same time you would have to create a more complex timer and listener handler, which seems not to be in the question.
The way it works is that when you want to create one of these "custom" timers you can add something truthy as the third parameter of `window.setTimeout`: I think this is good practice otherwise you risk compromising your own function because if a library calls that method it would reset your timer.

```js
(function() {
  // Store the native method here
  var nativeSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;

  window.bindTimeout = function(listener) {
    // Declare a couple of variables in this scope
    var timerStart, timerDelay

    // This function will return the value saved in that variable
    function getTimeLeft() {
      // If there's no custom timer running, pass undefined to the listener
      if (!timerStart) return listener()

      // Calculate the difference between the expected end of the timer and the current time
      let ms_diff = new Date(timerStart.getTime() + timerDelay) - new Date()
      return listener(ms_diff)
    }

    function setTimeout(callback = () => {}, delay) {
      // Initialize the variables
      timerStart = new Date()
      timerDelay = delay

      return nativeSetTimeout(() => {
        timerStart = undefined
        timerDelay = undefined
        callback()
      }, delay)
    }

    // Edit the native method to switch to the custom timers only when the last argument is added
    window.setTimeout = (callback, delay, custom) => (custom ? setTimeout : nativeSetTimeout)(callback, delay);

    return getTimeLeft
  };
}());

let getTime = window.bindTimeout(t => ((t || 'No ') + 'ms remaining.'));
// The time variable will store a function that will give you the value when called

// If you call it before the timeout has been set it will return undefined
console.log(getTime())

window.setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("All done.");
}, 1000, true) // The last option is checked, this timeout will be custom

// If you call it just after setting the timeout it'll show the total delay 
console.log(getTime())

// If you wait for the timeout to start it will return the right value
window.setTimeout(() => console.log(getTime()), 123)
window.setTimeout(() => console.log(getTime()), 456)
window.setTimeout(() => console.log(getTime()), 789)

// If called after the timeout has finished, it will go back to returning undefined
window.setTimeout(() => console.log(getTime()), 1500)
```

Comment: buddy I wrote that there is no problem in the explanation? assign it to a variable and use "time" for example....

" window.bindTimeout(t => console.log(t + 'ms remaining'), 100);"  that way I know how to do it too, but it constantly prints to the console I want it to be inside a variable and invoke it using that variable.

Comment: Edited, take a look now

Comment: this is the same thing 
it does not work does not print the variable to the console again undefined?

Comment: Sorry, but don't you see the result in the console when running the code snippet? It works for everything that is called after the timeout is started. I've now edited the code to initialize the value with the delay, but if this is not working then I must be really misunderstanding your question...

Comment: PS: there's still an `undefined` in the log, but read the code comments before commenting about that

Comment: yes i read but i need to pull the variable without interval @Federico Grandi